# bug in TListview

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

I think I found a potential bug in TListView.

When you bind the ListView with a DataSource and would like to delete the last item in the list by wiping to the left/right then there comes an error. (Translated: Value out of the bound)

I have investigated and discovered that the `COUNT` number is not the actual count number of items in the delete routine. If I have one item the count number is 0.

When I create a ListView with the `.ADD` method, then the count number is fine and the deleting works also fine.

Is there a workaround available?

Well in the code you can not see much. Last item in ListViewSprache can be deleted by wiping but ListView1 creates an error after selecteing some records from my SQLite DB and want to wipe the last item. I have uploaded the whole demo project to [bug.zip](https://www.physiological-chemistry.at/uploads/media/bug.zip)but you must run it on Android, which support deleting by wiping on the selected ListView Item.

```
  unit Unit1;

  interface

  uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
    FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListView, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
    FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
    FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,
    FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.FMXUI.Login,
    FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
    System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt,
    Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.DBScope, Data.DB,
    FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Comp.UI;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      ListView1: TListView;
      ButtonAdd: TButton;
      ListViewSprache: TListView;
      FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
      FDGUIxLoginDialog1: TFDGUIxLoginDialog;
      FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
      FDQueryCreateTable: TFDQuery;
      BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
      BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
      LinkFillControlToField1: TLinkFillControlToField;
      procedure ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private-Deklarationen }
    public
      { Public-Deklarationen }
    end;

  var
    Form1: TForm1;
    LItem : TListViewItem;

  implementation

  {$R *.fmx}

  procedure TForm1.ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
      ListViewSprache.BeginUpdate;
      try
           LItem := ListViewSprache.Items.Add;
           LItem.Text := 'Deutsch';        // itemindex = 0
           LItem := ListViewSprache.Items.Add;
           LItem.Text := 'English';     // itemindex = 1
      finally
        ListViewSprache.EndUpdate;
      end;
  end;

  end.
```

[image: Live Binding Design of my Query with ListVIEW]

Comment: You should add a working, minimal example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Agreed. Some code is needed for us to be sure we know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I have edited my Q. Please note that on WIN32 wiping-delete is not implemented. (YOU must use Andorid)